# Thunderbird - Get the user email address

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I am developing a Mozilla Thunderbird plug-in and need to get the user's email address.

**Question:** How do I retrieve this address?

I will use it inside a JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first keep in mind that a user can have multiple e-mail addresses (from multiple accounts or even multiple identities for one account), and you have to decide in which one you are interested.

*Note: there may exist an easier way then described below, e.g. a helper function in the existing Thunderbird Code. You could try to search [comm-central](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/) for it*

You somehow have to get the [`nsIMsgIdentity`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgIdentity.idl) for the identity you are interested in. It has an `email` property, with the e-mail adress as a string.

One way to get all Identities should be via the `allIdentities` of [`nsIMsgAccountManager`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgAccountManager.idl) (didn't test it).

Use the follwing code to get the [`nsIMsgAccountManager`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgAccountManager.idl):

```
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/mailServices.js");
let accountManager = MailServices.accounts
```

If you have an `nsIArray` of [`nsIMsgIdentity`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgIdentity.idl), you can use the following code to loop over them:

```
for (let identity in fixIterator(identities, Components.interfaces.nsIMsgIdentity)) {
}
```

#### References which could be useful:

Overview of some interesting interfaces:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Account_interfaces

Some account example Code:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Account_examples

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted! Thank you. And thanks for the references, now I know how and where to obtain the necessary knowledge for build my add-on.